# Bootstrap 3 mixing col-md-3 and col-sm-4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 3 rows divided into 4 columns for medium devices like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">image</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make these rows divided into 3 columns for small devices so it would end up in 4 rows with 3 columns ?

Comment: If the images aren't separated by category anyway, I don't think you need to explicitly separate the rows. Just have one row and let bootstrap align the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I learned recently, you can ditch all but one of those `div.row`s and everything will still work fine. As long as you are working with factors of 12, as you are (3x4 and 4x3), everything will lay out nicely.

Working example here: http://www.bootply.com/n0fmASOCI1

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```